# Accessing (full) Visual Studio project properties after switching to platform toolset v90

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I've installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1 C++ Express Edition, 2010 Ultimate and 2013 Premium.

I've opened my old Visual Studio 2008 project with VS 2013 and upgraded the Project Files.
Afterwards I've changed the Platform Toolset to v90.

The project is compiling fine but is there a way to access the project properties? I can't even find a way to switch back to the v120 toolset (I don't want it tho).

Project -> Properties will only show the following properties:

[image]

Is there a way to access the full project properties?
It seems that choosing v100 will cause the same issue.

Comment: Hard to guess what you are clicking.  You changed the Toolset property so you at least *once* had no trouble getting to the project properties.

Comment: I click on the project -> Properties. Before changing the toolset I got the full properties view (the same windows as in the screenshot but with a lot more entries). After switching the toolset I'll get what you can see on the screenshot.